# Please login to use the PayPal sandbox feature

Tags: paypal, sandbox, paypal-sandbox

With the recent revamp of the PayPal developer site, I have encountered many problems trying to test my site with PayPal integration.

Issue 1:
I am not able to check out from out site which it should bring me to sandbox.paypal.com, it return me the common error of "Please login to use the PayPal sandbox feature". I have confirmed that I am logged in to the developer site at developer.paypal.com.

Issue 2:
Under Applications > Sandbox accounts, in one of the account, I am redirected to the live site at www.paypal.com by clicking on "Sandbox site". It should bring me to sandbox.paypal.com so I can login to the sandbox account. Currently this is not possible.

Issue 3:
I realised that I am logged out from developer.paypal.com when I go to www.paypal.com. Some kind of cookie issue?

Above all issues, I have tried troubleshooting by using a different browser, clearing cookies and cache.

Comment: Deleting all cookies bound to .paypal.com resolved issue 1 for me in firefox 20.0.1.

Answer (score 14):

Some of these issues are currently being worked on.  Some have been able to have been resolved by clearing the cache and cookies on your browser.  This must be done prior to opening up the developer.paypal.com site and most developers have better luck with this when using Firefox or Chrome.  There appear to be more issues with IE, than the other browsers.

If doing this does not resolve your issue, you will want to open up a ticket with [PayPal Merchant Technical Services](http://www.paypal.com/mts).  This way your issues can be tracked, and it will allow PayPal to gauge the number of merchants being effected by the different issues.  Also, this will allow you to be notified once the issue is resolved.

As a workaround, you could also try using the API credentials that are within the sample code/SDK's for testing purposes.  This will allow you to test the API calls, though you just will not be able to log into the Merchant account and make changes to it.  This may or may not work for you depending on your needs.

Comment: The problem seem to be intermittent. Sometime works but sometimes not. I'm on a Mac using Chrome and Safari. Have tried both browsers with the same problem. I guess PayPal have identified the issue and fixing it.

Comment: We are still working to address all of the issues.  Some have been resolved, but there are still issues that we are still working on.

Comment: @PP_MTS_Chad Thanks for your answer. I am getting the same issues. Where/how can we know that the issues have been resolved?

Comment: Your best option is to open up a ticket with PayPal MTS at www.paypal.com/mts so that your issue can be tracked, and it can help to gauage the number of accounts that are effected by these issues. This will also allow you to be notified where there is an update on the issue, and it has been resolved.

Comment: @PP_MTS_Chad It seems that above issues are resolved. Is it permanent or you guys will make further changes? Because it is MUST for me to test the payment things in this month. Many thanks for all you support.

Comment: Clearing cookies worked for me. (I deleted every cookie from any paypal domain).

Comment: maybe in 2014 or 2015 paypal will tackle this devious problem. logging in and cookies are super tricky. fingers crossed everybody.

Comment: I remember the headaches I had to go through integrating Paypal payment APIs back in 2008.  Ridiculous that 7 years later, even though the APIs have gone through multiple revamps, integration is still a huge pain in the ass.

Answer (score 6):

Trying different browsers worked for me.  I experienced the same problem for several hours today when using Firefox, Chrome, and Safari on Mac OSX 10.8.  I tested using Firefox 19.0 on a PC and things worked fine with the PayPal sandbox site.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues as the original poster. I was using IE9 with ExpressCheckout API.

I was calling the `SetExpressCheckout` and redirecting to PayPal sandbox. On the Sandbox login page, after typing login details of my test personal account I received a message that the email account was not valid and a link (which didn't work) to return to Sandbox site.

I switched to Firefox (which was also probably clean of cookies for the PayPal Sandbox as I don't recall ever testing PayPal using Firefox) and everything worked fine.

I called the `SetExpressCheckout`, redirected to PayPal sandbox and I could login with my test personal account and checkout and return correctly to my payment landing page to call `DoExpressCheckoutPayment`.

Comment: I have tried using a different browser (e.g. from chrome to firefox) and still no change.  I am using OSX.

Answer (score 0):

FYI in case anyone else is dealing with this problem. I am using the PayPal IPN feature, which in the Sandbox environment stopped working when I was doing some recent testing after migrating to the 'new' sandbox environment. I imported my old sandbox test accounts after logging into the developer site with my real paypal info, but still nothing worked. After messing around forever, I discovered that basically you have to setup again as if it was a new account even though you imported your old settings. I had to specify my IPN url again and also re-verify the old imported sandbox accounts via an email link that you receive under you paypal developer sandbox notifications. Then while logged in the developer site, you can log into the sandbox environment with your test accounts and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes the most simple solution:
Click your browsers back button and perform the step again.
Sounds stupid, but it works.