# Paypal : testing with sandbox account asks to login after redirection

Tags: php, paypal-sandbox

when using paypal sandbox. redirect to the test sandbox and shows like login to use the sandbox features:https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/in/cgi-bin/webscr

please help me to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

Just as the error message says, in order to use sandbox's features, you must already be logged into your sandbox account (not the user's paypal sandbox account, but the actual sandbox account)

**edit**: possible duplicate of [Please login to use the PayPal sandbox feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376551/please-login-to-use-the-paypal-sandbox-feature).

As that post mentions, the recent change in paypal's sandbox affected many users' ability to use it.

For my case, it wouldn't work with chrome as it previously did, unless I cleared all cache and cookies. It worked using firefox (which I used for the first time in paypal)

Comment: by clicking the link in that error message and logged in to the sandbox in different window tabs. again trying to buy a product. error message shows agains.