# Paypal IPN listener receiving wrong payment_status

Tags: paypal, sandbox

I'm using this form to submit a request on the paypal sandbox site:

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" 
    method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="MY_EMAIL">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Book!">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="13">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="THIS URL">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="MY_IPN">
    <input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" 
        border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

The only values I replace are `MY_EMAIL` and `MY_IPN`. The latter, in particular, is a link to my `ipn.php` file

```
include('ipnlistener.php');

$listener = new IpnListener();

// tell the IPN listener to use the PayPal test sandbox
$listener->use_sandbox = true;

// try to process the IPN POST
try {
    $listener->requirePostMethod();
    $verified = $listener->processIpn();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    error_log($e->getMessage());
}

error_log($listener->getTextReport());
```

[(ipnlistener.php source is on github)](https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN/blob/master/ipnlistener.php). When I place the order, everything works smoothly (apart from the [Please login to use the PayPal sandbox feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376551/please-login-to-use-the-paypal-sandbox-feature) bug, which I assume won't be there as I switch from the sandbox to the real paypal).

The problem is: the order is placed correctly and in my sandbox account I receive the payment

> ```
> Hello Test Store,
>
> You received a payment of €13.00 EUR from xxx xxx (xxx@test.test)
> ```

but in my error_log I see this:

```
payment_status           Pending
```

Should I code my ipn.php file such that it accepts and delivers the digital goods also if `payment_status` is set to `Pending`? The guide I'm following advise to do so only if payment_status is `Completed`.

Why isn't the paypal sandbox server sending me the confirmation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - just log in to your sandbox business account and, from there, enable the reception of payments in different currencies or/and accept the payment. Your IPN will then receive the "Completed" payment_status attribute correctly.