# always login failed in paypal sandbox

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm using [PayPal-PHP-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK) in laravel according to [this article](https://laravelcode.com/post/how-to-integrate-paypal-payment-gateway-in-laravel-54) to make a simple **paypal** payment gateway integration.

All things worked fine but each time to test a payment I redirect to payment page, can not login into my account and always shows me "**Check your email address and password and try again**".

I tried with other buyer accounts and get same error.

I followed all suggested solutions in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376551/please-login-to-use-the-paypal-sandbox-feature)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461110/cant-login-to-paypal-sandbox) including clearing cookies and test in other browser but problem is not solved.

I do not know what is problem and how can I solve it ?

Comment: Are you correctly connecting to the PayPal sandbox URI

Comment: yes, my Paypal url is : `https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/row/cgi-bin/merchantpaymentweb?cmd=_flow&SESSION=YBZG0ikbnI1eA27JAYDO6BDiHya7BtmZHB4Rgjzpg8hcoFjIili8TwP5CgW&dispatch=50a222a57771920b6a3d7b606239e4d529b525e0b7e69bf0224adecfb0124e9b61f737ba21b08198bdf3462ec1f5893fb648307135523787&rapidsState=OneX__ExpressCheckoutOneXFlow___StateNewLogin&rapidsStateSignature=(null)`

Comment: Paypal sandbox environment is beset with problems. About 50% of the time, it just does NOT work. I reckon, it was built on top of a legacy system, which was probably broken as well. Very poor...